# Change hover to always show (caption)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a portfolio website

www.malthestigaard.com

where I am displaying some portfolio cases using the Cube Portfolio JavaScript plugin. Each portfolio case has a caption connected to it that on a desktop shows at mouseover/hover. The problem is of course that when viewing my website on a mobile device there is no mouse to hover over the portfolio case and the caption remains hidden (as far as I can tell it hides the captions for specific screen sizes only, but as I am new to html and css I have a hard time figuring out where to find the right media queries and how to change them, plus I'm thinking it will benefit user experience if it just always shows). So my question is, how can I change the css or javascript so that the caption always shows?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="MUWlt9WTlzFb8HfafpTZqH5IG7Em-w30oBgQQZKX1jc" />
    <meta charset="uft-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.malthestigaard.com" />
    <meta name="author" content="Malthe Stigaard | www.malthestigaard.com">
    <meta name="description" content="Website and Portfolio of Malthe Stigaard | www.malthestigaard.com" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Digital Design, Print Design, Photography, Video Production, Web Design, Portfolio, Malthe Stigaard" />
    <meta name="geo.country" content="DK" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Portfolio of Malthe Stigaard" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Website and Portfolio of Malthe Stigaard | www.malthestigaard.com" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://malthestigaard.com/index.thml" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://malthestigaard.com/images/image-ogf.jpg" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Malthe Stigaard | Graphic &#38; Web Design | www.malthestigaard.com</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class=textclear>
                    <div class="alignleft">
                        <h1 class="firsth1"> <a href="http://www.malthestigaard.com"> MALTHE STIGAARD </a></h1></div>
                    <div class="alignright">
                        <ul>
                            <h1><li> <a href="#work" type="button"> WORK </a></li><li> <a href="#about" type="button"> ABOUT </a></li><li> <a href="#contact" type="button"> CONTACT </a></li></h1></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section id="banner">
            <div id="bannercontainer">
                <h2>I&#39;M MALTHE STIGAARD</h2>
                <div id="bannerlinescontainer">
                    <div class="grad"></div>
                    <h1><p>DIGITAL DESIGN<br>PRINT DESIGN<br>VIDEO PRODUCTION<br>PHOTOGRAPHY</p></h1>
                    <div class="grad"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>WELCOME TO MY PORTFOLIO</h2> <a href="#work" type="button" class="workbutton"> see my work </a></div>
        </section>
        <section id="work">
            <h1>MY WORK</h1>
            <div class="copytext"> Over a 12-year period I have been working on digital and print projects within the creative industry at a strategic, executive and production level. I have managed tasks of branding, UX design, UI design, web development, video production and photography. I have coordinated teams and carried out launches, marketing campaigns and assisted in communication strategies and business development. In brief I am a creative visual storyteller with a broad experience. Below you'll find a small collection of some of my work - take a look and feel free to <a href="#contact" class="bold color2"> share your opinion </a> with me.</div>
            <div id="js-filters-masonry" class="cbp-l-filters-alignLeft">
                <div data-filter="*" class="cbp-filter-item-active cbp-filter-item"> All
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".web-design" class="cbp-filter-item"> Web Design
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".graphic" class="cbp-filter-item"> Graphic
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".direct-response-marketing" class="cbp-filter-item"> Direct Response Marketing
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".construction" class="cbp-filter-item"> Construction
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".spatial-design" class="cbp-filter-item"> Spatial Design
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".photography" class="cbp-filter-item"> Photography
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".editorial" class="cbp-filter-item"> Editorial
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-filter=".video" class="cbp-filter-item"> Video
                    <div class="cbp-filter-counter"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="js-grid-masonry" class="cbp">
                <div class="cbp-item web-design">
                    <a href="images/portfolio-case-01.jpg" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox" data-title="<p>Mobile and Desktop Website</p><p><a href='http://jonasroberts.dk/' target='_blank'>TAKE ME TO THE WEBSITE</a></p>">
                        <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="images/portfolio-case-01-thumbnail.jpg" alt="portfolio Malthe Stigaard"></div>
                        <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                            <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">Personal Trainer Jonas Roberts</div>
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-desc">Mobile and Desktop Website</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </section>
        <section id="about">
            <h1> ABOUT ME</h1>
            <h2> WHAT I DO</h2>
            <div id="cubepanel">
                <div id="js-filters-tabs" class="cbp-l-filters-big">
                    <div data-filter=".tools" class="cbp-filter-item-active cbp-filter-item"> TOOLS I USE</div>
                    <div data-filter=".languages" class="cbp-filter-item"> WEB LANGUAGES</div>
                    <div data-filter=".media" class="cbp-filter-item"> PHOTOGRAPHY & VIDEO</div>
                </div>
                <div id="js-grid-tabs" class="cbp cbp-l-grid-tabs">
                    <div class="cbp-item tools"> For the past 10 years I have worked professionally with the Adobe Creative Suite. I am particularly experienced in Photoshop, Indesign, Premiere Pro and Bridge. I also have 5 years of professional experience with Final Cut Pro + extensions.</div>
                    <div class="cbp-item languages"> I have 2 years of experience in coding HTML 5 and CSS 3. I know JavaScript and jQuery to the extent that I can implement plugins in HTML, and apply basic adjustments.</div>
                    <div class="cbp-item media"> I have trained as a photographer and as a videographer. Within photography I have covered mostly event photography, product photography, architectural photography and artistic photography. My video productions include documentaries, art house films and company films, contributing as producer, director, camera operator and editor.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2> CLIENTS & COLLABORATIONS</h2>
            <p id="previous" class="copytext">OLYMPUS
                <br>DANSK KOMMUNIKATIONSFORENING
                <br>TNT ARKITEKTER 
                <br>GERRIT RIETVELD ACADEMIE
                <br>MOTORIOUS
                <br>RIETWOOD STICHTING 
                <br>PERSONLIG TR&AElig;NER JONAS ROBERTS 
                <br>TR&AElig;SKIBS SAMMENSLUTNING
                <br>FATAMORGANA 
                <br>PLUS 2 
                <br>MONTH OF PERFORMANCE ART 
                <br>HOMEBASE LAB 
                <br>SERENITY 
                <br>BREAST FRIENDS 
                <br>DANSK ICYE 
                <br>M4 GASTATELIER 
                <br>PIONER
                <br>START POINT PRIZE 
                <br>AIR ANTWERPEN 
                <br>MONDRIAAN FONDS 
                <br>ARBOR VITAE FOUNDATION 
                <br>DANSK KUNSTR&Aring;D
                <br>
            </p>
        </section>
        <section id="spare">
            <h1> IN MY SPARE TIME</h1>
            <p class="copytext"> FITNESS OR SWIMMING AFTER WORK, KEEPING MYSELF UPDATED WITH WHAT'S GOING ON IN THE TECH WORLD. I LOVE A GOOD STORY, AS WELL AS GOOD MOVIES AND ART. I LIKE TO TRAVEL EUROPE TO VISIT FRIENDS WITHIN THE EUROPEAN CREATIVE COMMUNITY. AND I SPEND A CONSIDERABLE AMOUNT OF TIME THINKING ABOUT WORD DEFINITIONS AND LANGUAGES.</p>
        </section>
        <section id="contact">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="vertical-align"> <img src="images/portrait-malthe-stigaard.jpg" alt="portrait Malthe Stigaard"></div>
                <div class="vertical-align">
                    <h1> CONTACT</h1>
                    <p class="white"> I would love to hear from you, write me at <a href="mailto:ms@malthestigaard.com">ms@malthestigaard.com</a>
                        <br> and find me on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/malthe.stigaard">Facebook</a>, <a href="https://dk.linkedin.com/in/malthe-stigaard-32b2b246">LinkedIn</a> and <a href="https://www.instagram.com/malthestigaard/">Instagram</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p> &#169; 2016 Malthe Stigaard</p>
        </footer>
        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
            var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
            if (target.length) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
        (function($, window, document, undefined) {
            'use strict';
            $('#js-grid-tabs').cubeportfolio({
                filters: '#js-filters-tabs',
                defaultFilter: '.tools',
                animationType: 'fadeOut',
                gridAdjustment: 'default',
                displayType: 'default',
                caption: '',
            });
        })(jQuery, window, document);
        (function($, window, document, undefined) {
            'use strict';
            $('#js-grid-masonry').cubeportfolio({
                filters: '#js-filters-masonry',
                layoutMode: 'grid',
                defaultFilter: '*',
                animationType: 'slideDelay',
                gapHorizontal: 20,
                gapVertical: 20,
                gridAdjustment: 'responsive',
                mediaQueries: [{
                    width: 1500,
                    cols: 4
                }, {
                    width: 1100,
                    cols: 4
                }, {
                    width: 800,
                    cols: 3
                }, {
                    width: 480,
                    cols: 2,
                    options: {
                        caption: ''
                    }
                }, {
                    width: 320,
                    cols: 1,
                    options: {
                        caption: ''
                    }
                }],
                caption: 'overlayBottom',
                displayType: 'bottomToTop',
                displayTypeSpeed: 100,
                lightboxDelegate: '.cbp-lightbox',
                lightboxGallery: true,
                lightboxTitleSrc: 'data-title',
                lightboxCounter: '<div class="cbp-popup-lightbox-counter">{{current}} of {{total}}</div>',
            });
        })(jQuery, window, document);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#grid-container').cubeportfolio({});
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Google Analytics tracking code -->
    <script>
        (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-34485670-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you create a snippet / fiddle?

Comment: what about your css?

Comment: How to post CSS if the CSS is extremely long? I tried to create a snippet, but it would not except character lenght... What do you guys normally do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The captions are positioned at the bottom of the container with CSS, and the `bottom` attribute is changed on hover. You can set the bottom to 0(in your media queries) and the captions will always be in view.

Add to the bottom of your css:

`.cbp-caption-overlayBottom .cbp-caption-activeWrap { bottom: 0;}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm! I also had to remove from CSS the
         
        .cbp-caption-overlayBottom .cbp-caption:hover .cbp-caption-activeWrap {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%)
        }

To avoid the text jumping further up on hover :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```css
.card {
  background-color: #3498db;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.caption {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.card:hover .caption {
  visibility: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .caption {
    visibility:visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="caption">
    Hello this is a caption
  </div>
</div>
```

The `:hover` properties are re-write in the media querie that you want without the `:hover`.

Comment: The captions aren't hidden, they're just positioned out of view. Though you're right about the `@media` rule.

Comment: The captions are hidden in desktop view, but he want them to be always visible on the mobile view if I understand correclty the question.